# List of documents in Entire Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, document

I am trying to get a list of all documents within my SharePoint Site, owner and date last modified.

It is a `SharePoint 2010 Enterprise` environment.

It's a site which has many subsites.

All solutions I have tried only allow me to get documents at that specific site level and not subsites.

I must admit, I can get the required information by querying the SQL DB directly but don't want to go down this path, as it's unsupported by MS

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you after documents in document libraries only, or documents attached to list items too? It'll be a similar process for each, to be fair.

Comment: At a high level, after all documents in a SharePoint Site, so would be the Libraries - the final goal is to decommission SharePoint and put our files back in file servers.

Comment: @Rakesh still no answer? if yes please mark it

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information quite easy by using Powershell, you just need to iterate through all subsites and document libraries.

Take a look at these pages:

http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2010/08/getting-an-inventory-of-all-sharepoint-documents-using-windows-powershell/
(This is almost exactly what you require, there are a few extra lines that you don't need).

http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/get-all-document-libraries-in-a-site-collection.html

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/126397/powershell-get-a-list-of-all-the-document-libraries-for-a-web-application-incl

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varun_malhotra/archive/2012/02/08/sharepoint-2010-powershell-download-all-files-in-document-library-to-network-share-file-share.aspx